# PHP random/percentage chance to do one of the options

Tags: php, logic

I'm looking to have a link that if a user presses it generates a random number, that number is then compared to a bunch of if statements to do something e.g something like this:

```
$value = rand(1,1000);
```

Then if statements:

```
if ($value >= 1 && $value <= 10) {
// do something
} elseif ($value >= 11 && $value <= 20) {
// do something else
} .... etc
```

Each random click/number will only relate to one of the if statements, so only one output should happen.

This doesn't seem the most logical/simplest way to do this. Unsure what the best method would be here. Could anyone point me in the right direction of other methods to achieve something like this? Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on what your goals are, and you haven't really told us that. For instance: Are the "somethings to do" interdependent or independent? How many of those "somethings" have to be done? Can the number vary or not?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ah sorry! Only one of them will be performed. So the user randoms one number. That number is say 600. That equates to one specific if statement/do something.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [switch statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) like this:

```
$numberOfSomethings = 5;

switch (rand(1,$numberOfSomethings)) {
    case 1: 
        // do something number 1
        break;
    case 2: 
        // do something number 2
        break;
    case 3: 
        // do something number 3
        break;
    case 4: 
        // do something number 4
        break;
    case 5: 
        // do something number 5
        break;
}
```

but this looks very much like your code.

You could do the "something" inside functions and then call a random function:

```
function something1()
{
    // do something number 1
}

function something2()
{
    // do something number 3
}

function something3()
{
    // do something number 3
}

$functionName = "something".rand(1,3); // choose a function
$functionName(); // and call it
```

This seems easy to expand. But I still think your goals are not very clear.

Comment: Thanks! The functions might be a good idea. To expand a little on what I'm after. Its basically a "cave" the user is entering. When they enter they roll a random event that happens within the cave. I want to be able to have some with higher odds of happening, some with lower etc. So user enters the cave, they roll a 500, 500 is in in the if statement that say give the user some gold for example. Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So the odds of each event happening are not the same. That changes things. Clearly the odds are all the same in my examples.

Comment: Thats gonna be alot of cases to write.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are after is thresholds with callbacks.  So what you need to build is an array of thresholds that have a callback.  Then when you generate your random number you just iterate through the thresholds and compare your random number to the threshold value.

```
 $number = rand(1, 1000);

 $thresholds = [
    [10,function(){}],
    [20,function(){}],
    [30,function(){}]
 ];

 //now we can loop through each threshold with the random number.  As we only need to check the last highest value of each to know we passed the threshold.

 foreach($thresholds as $index=> $threshold){
   //we need to check if this is the last threshold first so we need to know what that is.   
   if(array_key_last($threshold) === $index){
      $threshold[1]();
      break;
   }

   //here we check if the number is greater than the threshold and also less than the next threshold. then call its callback.
   elseif($number >= $threshold[0] && $number < $thresholds[$index + 1][0]){
      $threshold[1]();
      break;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You liked the function idea, but you need varying odds. That can be done with a lookup array. So we still have these functions:

```
function something1()
{
    // do something number 1
}

function something2()
{
    // do something number 3
}

function something3()
{
    // do something number 3
}
```

but now we use a lookup array like this:

```
$events = ['something1' => 3,
           'something2' => 1,
           'something3' => 5];
```

The total sum of that array is 9, and `something2` has a 1 in 9 chance of occurring, `something1` a 1 in 3 chance and `something3` a 5 in 9 chance.

Now we still need to call a function using these chances, that can be done this way:

```
$total  = array_sum($events);
$number = rand(1, $total);
$sum    = 0;
foreach ($events as $functionName => $chance) {
    $sum += $chance;
    if ($sum >= $number) {
        $functionName();
        break;
    }
}
```